# Check if computer have a CDROM?

Tags: hardware, dvd, data-cd

ALL,

In the past there was a standard to have a floppy drive on the computer.

Now even CD-ROM is optional.

Is there a way to find out if the device is present on the machine? Not mounted, not the disk in - just check for the actual physical device presence on the laptop.

If its at all possible with GTK+ - it would be great. Otherwise maybe just with a system command.

TIA!!

I couldn't find any "cdrom" tags, so just marked it as hardware

Answer (score 3):

`ls -l /dev/cdrom` may show something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Mar  8 17:23 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
```

`lsblk` should show something like:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda             8:0    0 950.5G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    50G  0 part  /
├─sda2          8:2    0    16G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda3          8:3    0   745G  0 part  /home
├─sda4          8:4    0   139G  0 part
└─sda5          8:5    0   568M  0 part
sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Neither of those are 100% reliable and may depend on the actual distro you're running, but they're as close as you're going to get.